# Interpreting coefficients table in ordinal regression

Tags: r, regression

Can we interpret the coefficients of an ordinal regression in the coefficients table without involving the intercepts?

For example

```
library(ordinal)

> head(wine)
  response rating temp contact bottle judge
1       36      2 cold      no      1     1
2       48      3 cold      no      2     1
3       47      3 cold     yes      3     1
4       67      4 cold     yes      4     1
5       77      4 warm      no      5     1
6       60      4 warm      no      6     1

fm <- clm(rating ~ temp * contact, data=wine)
summary(fm)

Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
tempwarm              2.3212     0.7009   3.311 0.000928 ***
contactyes            1.3475     0.6604   2.041 0.041300 *  
tempwarm:contactyes   0.3595     0.9238   0.389 0.697129    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Threshold coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error z value
1|2  -1.4113     0.5454  -2.588
2|3   1.1436     0.5097   2.244
3|4   3.3771     0.6382   5.292
4|5   4.9420     0.7509   6.581
```

**What does the `contactyes` coefficient mean on its own?**

EDIT:
Here are the plots for the probabilities per rating level

[image]

Comment: How did you go from "temp" in the model statiemnt to "tempwarm" in the coefficients?

Comment: @PeterFlom Treatment contrasts. `temp` is a factor variable with "warm" as the second level. (I suspect the first level could be "cold".)

Comment: @PeterFlom, temp is a factor with two levels, cold and warm (see edit).

Comment: Oh. OK. And the output unhelpfully doesn't put a space between the name of the factor and the level.  That's R for you.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

The contactyes coefficient is the odds ratio for contact for each level of rating when temp = 0. (Or tempwarm. See my comment, something odd there).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I interpret `contactyes` like this?: `warmer` wines with `contact=yes` are more likely to receive a higher rating than `colder` wines with `contact=no`. Is that correct? I'm struggling because in linear regression we have a single intercept and single equation, but here we have 4, one for `1|2`, `2|3`, `3|4` and `4|5`, so I'm not sure if my interpretation makes sense.

Comment: Or maybe more precisely: `warmer` wines with a `contact=yes` increase the odds of a higher rating relative to `colder` wines with `contact=no` by 1.34. The "higher rating" part is what confuses me, since it seems so unspecific...

Comment: "Higher rating" is between any two levels, because ordinal logistic assumes proportional odds.  

"contactyes" by itself refers to the case when temp = cool. When temp = warm, you need to also add in the interaction term. Since that is positive, the effect of temperature is greater when contact = yes.

Comment: An introduction to the proportional odds semiparametric ordinal logistic model is [here](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/nonpar#generalization-of-the-wilcoxonkruskal-wallis-test) which shows how to interpret the coefficient in some detail.

Comment: Ah, yes, I messed up. The interpretation of `contactyes` should be that colder wines with contact=yes are 1.34 more likely to receive a higher rating than colder wines with contact=no, correct?

Comment: I think it's the "between any two levels" that I don't seem to be able to understand. At first I thought this must mean that the increase in odds ratio of 1.34 for colder wines with contact=yes relative to colder wines with contact=no is the same between Rating 1 and Rating 2, between Rating 2 and Rating 3, and so on. But that cannot be right, as these plots show: `library(ggeffects); plot(ggpredict(fm, terms=c("temp","contact")))`

Comment: I can't see the plots, just the code.  You may be able to add the actual plots to your question.

Comment: @PeterFlom, edited the question with the plots. From these plots, I can see that the difference between contact=yes and contact=no for colder wines is very different among Ratings. 
It's still very unclear to me what the coefficient `contactyes` is telling me, and how it relates to those plots.

Comment: I think I may be incorrect, see @FrankHarrell 's link in his comment.

Comment: @locus replace 'more likely' with '1.34 times higher odds'.

Comment: @FrankHarrell, thanks for your comment. OK, so the interpretation of `contactyes` coefficient is that colder wines with contact=yes have 1.34 times higher odds to receive a higher rating than colder wines with contact=no.

Comment: My problem now is where do the different rating levels fit here? If this were multiple regression, it would be easy for me to visualize a line passing through different values of `y`. But with this ordinal model, I just can't see how the coefficient `contactyes` relates to the different ratings.

Comment: There are many ways to display the results of an ordinal model, including using it to estimate mean of Y | X and nomograms to estimate all the exceedance probabilities as well as the mean and quantiles of Y.  See several examples in [RMS](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc) and [BBR](https://hbiostat.org/bbr).