# interpretation of trends in ordinal regression with emmeans

Tags: ordinal-data, lsmeans

I'm using `emmeans` to extract trends from an interaction of two factors, one categorical (`temp`) and one continuous (`response`).

```
library(ordinal)
library(emmeans)

wine2 <- wine
wine2$rating[wine2$rating==5] <- 1
wine2$rating <- ordered(wine2$rating)

fm <- clm(rating ~ response*temp, data=wine2)

emtrends(fm, ~temp, var="response")

temp response.trend     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
cold         0.1448 0.0296 Inf    0.0867    0.2029
warm        -0.0117 0.0247 Inf   -0.0601    0.0366
```

I'm not sure how to interpret these trends, since I always thought ordinal regression should take into consideration the different intercepts in the model. Without looking at the different levels of rating (1|2, 2|3, 3|4), how should I interpret the output above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It always helps to look at [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/models.html#O). **emmeans** offers several `mode` settings for ordinal models. The default is on the latent scale. For examples, please see [this vignette section](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/sophisticated.html#ordinal).

It would also be helpful to read some of the vignettes in the **ordinal** package.

As you have coded, you did not specify `mode`, so it used the default, which is `latent`. The latent variable does not have separate intercepts. Instead, it is a constructed variable having a logistic distribution such that you will obtain the estimated cumulative probabilities at each cut point of that distribution. The higher the latent value, the lower the cumulative probability is at a given cut point.

If you do

```
emmip(fm, temp ~ response, cov.reduce = range)
```

then you see the following plot
[image: Interaction plot of the latent response]

As can be visualized, when `temp` is warm, the estimated mean on the latent scale hardly changes with `response`, whereas when the temp is cold, the latent mean increases with response. The estimates you obtained with `emtrends` are just the slopes of those two lines.

As I indicated above, you really should look at the vignettes for the **ordinal** package to get more of an explanation of the latent variable.

All that said, this particular example seems devoid of meaning, because `rating` is just a discretization of `response`, but then the highest and lowest rating got conflated together. This makes no sense at all.

Comment: Thanks @RussLenth. I had read the documentation and the vignettes from emmeans before posting, and I'm aware of the different modes for ordinal models. My question is more related to the interpretation of the emtrends output in my question. I can use `mode="prob"` to get the estimates of each rating, which I understand. But I'm struggling understanding what the `cold` and `warm` trends mean in the output above when it is not split by the levels of `rating`.

Comment: I asked a similar [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/625163/interpreting-coefficients-table-in-ordinal-regression) a few weeks ago about `clm`, but unfortunately did not receive very clear answers.

Comment: @locus I added to the answer.